# How to change host name in wincvs

Tags: hostname, wincvs

recently ip address of the computer where the sourcecodes are changed, so I need to change the ip address of hostname in wincvs. So I couldn't figure out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to change to ip address. But instead I was able to checkout to a new directory by checking Check out to  directory in checkout setting and I have also checked CVSROOT, there I specify the ip address. Now everything is fine. 
Thanks